# Flutter application cannot run ,show Gradle task assemble Debug failed with exit code -1

Tags: android, flutter

1 Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
X Android license status unknown.
Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
2 if am install my SDK tools in our android studio but command prompt show again and again
that one error Android SDK manager tool not found (C:\Users\Sourav\App Data\Local\Android\SDK\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat).
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK plz solve that issue I can check every link in google but my issue cannot solved

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
flutter config --android-sdk <path-to-your-android-sdk-path>
```

e.g

```
flutter config --android-sdk "C:\Users[your Local user folder]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk"
```

Small note : You can found Sdk in local user folder
**C:\Users<LocalFolderName>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk**